# Groovy: Is it possible to adapt Annotations in a proxied object?

Tags: groovy, annotations

say I have a class with an annotation

```
@SomeAnnotation
class Foo {}
```

In my code I have a proxy object via

```
def foo = new Foo()
def result = foo.asType(barType)
```

where `barType` is one or the other interface. `result` is now of a dynamically generated Groovy proxy class.

Is it possible to mess around with that class such that the `Foo`-Annotations are visible on `result.getClass().getAnnotations()`?

Comment: Can you give an example if how this might be used?

Comment: `Foo` shall be serialized by a ReST component and therefore has some JAX-RS annotations (alternatively Jackson may be used). But actually the proxied object is getting serialized.

Comment: I think it's possible to change the marshaling/unmarshaling so you can serialize/deserialize the foo object and not the proxied object. Take a look in java Serializable interface.